# Watch for variable change do not work

Tags: vue.js

I need to check variable `rasters_previews_list` for changing. Here is my code:

```
var userContent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<p>Some template</p>',
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      rasters_previews_list: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'rasters_previews_list': function(value, mutation) {
      console.log("Value changed");      
    }
  }
});
```

But In console I do not see `Value changed` when it got new data.

Data changing function:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
//...

   Vue.http.post('/dbdata', DataBody).then((response) => {
      userContent.rasters_previews_list = response; // putting JSON answer to Component data in userContent

      console.log(response);


      }, (response) => {
          console.log("Can't get list rasters metadata from DB. Server error: ", response.status)
      });
```

I change value in `map.on('draw:created', function (e)` (Leaflet JS). I see console.log output, so seems data is changing.

Comment: You are never changing the value in your code

Comment: @gurghet I change data from outside

Comment: Have you had success with the provided answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the value of an array you will have to use the special Array extension methods `Vue.set` and `Vue.delete`.

> Due to limitations of JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an Array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[0] = {}`;
> - When you modify the length of the Array, e.g. `vm.items.length = 0`.

https://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set

This problem is also mentioned in the [common gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. arr[0] = val) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method arr.$set(index, value) which is just syntax sugar for arr.splice(index, 1, value).

Comment: how to add `set` inside `Vue.extend` in data?

Comment: I suggest you to carefully read the documentation as it's clearly explained there. Anyways you don't use `set` inside `Vue.extend`, you use `set` to change the array. In the code you posted you are not changing the array. Please show where you are changing the array.

Comment: Can I do it's like: `userContent.$set('rasters_previews_list', response);`  ? Here is part where value is changing.

I am getting error: `Cannot read property '$set' of undefined`

I am changing array at string: ` userContent.rasters_previews_list = response;`

Comment: `userContent` is a constructor, it does not have any live data. You can act only on instances of `userContent` (id est: `var instance = new userContent({})`), morover `$set` is a method in Vue only for arrays

Comment: So I should move `rasters_previews_list` to Vue.data ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: could you show how I can fix my code please, I can't understand what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119009/discussion-between-gurghet-and-user1432751).